# Renaming an uploaded file in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Using CodeIgniter, I am trying to modify the name of the uploaded file to camelCase by removing any spaces and capitalizing subsequent words.

I am pretty sure that I can rename the file using the second parameter of move_uploaded_file but I don't even know where to look to figure out how to modify the name to camelCase.

Thanks in advance!
Jon

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out CI's upload library:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Let's first take a look at how to do a simple file upload without changing the filename:

```
$config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png';

$this->upload->initialize($config);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
}   
else
{
    $file_data = $this->upload->data();
}
```

It's that simple and it works quite well.

Now, let's take a look at the meat of your problem. First we need to get the file name from the $_FILES array:

```
$file_name = $_FILES['file_var_name']['name'];
```

Then we can split the string with a `_` delimiter like this:

```
$file_name_pieces = split('_', $file_name);
```

Then we'll have to iterate over the list and make a new string where all except the first spot have uppercase letters:

```
$new_file_name = '';
$count = 1;

foreach($file_name_pieces as $piece)
{
    if ($count !== 1)
    {
        $piece = ucfirst($piece);
    }

    $new_file_name .= $piece;
    $count++;
}
```

Now that we have the new filename, we can revisit what we did above. Basically,  you do everything the same except you add this $config param:

```
$config['file_name'] = $new_file_name;
```

And that should do it! By default, CI has the `overwrite` $config param set to `FALSE`, so if there are any conflicts, it will append a number to the end of your filename. For the full list of parameters, see the link at the top of this post.

Comment: Great answer! That helps me alot.

Comment: I'm trying to switch from using the `_` delimiter to using the `.`. In terms of exploding on the `.` delimiter, a file name using `.` instead of `_` makes more sense. However, for some reason the save isn't taking my `.` names, but insists on using `_`. Anybody run into this kind of problem renaming images with CI?

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->load->helper('inflector');
$file_name = underscore($_FILES['file_var_name']['name']);
$config['file_name'] = $file_name;
```

that should work too

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', ucwords($_FILES['file_var_name']['name']));
```