# Codeigniter upload adding underscore to filename

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter's built in upload library. These are my upload settings:

```
$config['upload_path'] = upload_path() . 'incoming_faxes/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'xml|pdf';
$config['file_name'] = uniqid('fax-' . time() . '-', true) . '.xml';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

It does work. The returned data is below, however the `file_name` has an underscore appended:

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => fax-1377114300-521518bca7c5a7.65243756_.xml
    [file_type] => application/xml
    [file_path] => /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/uploads/incoming_faxes/
    [full_path] => /var/www/vhosts/example.org/httpdocs/uploads/incoming_faxes/fax-1377114300-521518bca7c5a7.65243756_.xml
    [raw_name] => fax-1377114300-521518bca7c5a7.65243756_
    [orig_name] => fax-1377114300-521518bca7c5a7.65243756_.xml
    [client_name] => Sample.xml
    [file_ext] => .xml
    [file_size] => 84.69
    [is_image] => 
    [image_width] => 
    [image_height] => 
    [image_type] => 
    [image_size_str] => 
)
```

How can I remove the underscore before the file is uploaded to the server?

Comment: Try adding `'remove_spaces' => FALSE` to your config array and see if that takes care of the problem. This is set to TRUE by default, but it should only be replacing spaces with underscores. It could be a CI bug with the file uploading class.

Comment: @Fred-ii- good idea, didn't work though.

Comment: Have a look at this answer on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/4074238/1415724

Comment: Also consult https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1380 but from what I read on http://cs.au.dk/~grav/hypweb/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html the `remove_spaces` option should have worked. See also http://www.techques.com/question/1-5728059/Changing-name-of-the-uploaded-file-in-CodeIgniter-%28dots---underscores%29

Comment: Check `Line 994, _prep_filename()` function in `system->libraries->Upload.php file.` taken from this page http://ch.runcode.us/q/changing-name-of-the-uploaded-file-in-codeigniter-dots-underscores

Comment: Last resort. You could probably do a replacement using something to the affect of `$filename = str_replace("_","",$filename);` if that will work with CodeIgniter. There's a way to do it so that it finds the last underscore in a file, but I don't remember how to do it. I think you would have to use `mb_substr` or `substr` or `rtrim` to do that.

Comment: There's a patch added [here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commit/0eb5a66156b0252e24b71212a0c83cae3a24fa0f) which allows you to replace all the dots, except the last one (which you're adding before file ext) but it looks like it has been removed from current master branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$fn = uniqid('fax-' . time() . '-', true);
$filename = preg_replace('/\./','_', $fn) . '.xml';
```

Should do it.

Test:

```
$parts      = explode('.', $filename);
$ext        = array_pop($parts);
$filename   = array_shift($parts);

foreach ($parts as $part)
{
    if ( 1==1)
    {
        $filename .= '.'.$part.'_';
    }
    else
    {
        $filename .= '.'.$part;
    }
}


$filename .= '.'.$ext;

echo $filename;//fax-1377117024-52152360903ae2_02709878.xml
```

It looks like what's happening is the `_prep_filename()` method in Upload.php checks the `allowed_types` and `mimes_types` against the exploded filename. The period in your filename splits off the last number before the extension (65243756 in your example filename) into the `parts` array. It then checks this value against `allowed_types` and `mimes_types`. Unable to find the number in `allowed_types` nor in `mimes_types`, it appends the underscore.

It's a strange issue. See here for more info: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1380

Breaking it down:

```
// system/core/libraries/Upload.php
// line 984
protected function _prep_filename($filename)
{
    if (strpos($filename, '.') === FALSE OR $this->allowed_types == '*')
    {
        return $filename;
    }

    $parts      = explode('.', $filename);
    $ext        = array_pop($parts);
    $filename   = array_shift($parts);

    foreach ($parts as $part)
    {
        if ( ! in_array(strtolower($part), $this->allowed_types) OR $this->mimes_types(strtolower($part)) === FALSE)
        {
            $filename .= '.'.$part.'_';
        }
        else
        {
            $filename .= '.'.$part;
        }
    }

    $filename .= '.'.$ext;

    return $filename;
}
```

Given file name `fax-1377114300-521518bca7c5a7.65243756.xml`, this is what happens.

```
$parts     = explode('.', $filename);
```

this breaks up `$filename` into an array containing 3 values:

```
print_r($parts); //Array ( [0] => fax-1377119574-52152d561f4694 [1] => 21065888 [2] => xml )
```

next line...

```
$ext       = array_pop($parts);
```

`pop`s the `$parts` array:

```
print_r($parts); //Array ( [0] => fax-1377119706-52152dda0205e5 [1] => 29551151 )
```

next line...

```
$filename   = array_shift($parts);
```

`shift`s the array:

```
print_r($parts); //Array ( [0] => 39795691 )
```

so that now `$parts` contains only one item: `39795691`.

Now it runs

```
foreach ($parts as $part)
{
    if ( ! in_array(strtolower($part), $this->allowed_types) OR $this->mimes_types(strtolower($part)) === FALSE)
    {
        $filename .= '.'.$part.'_';
    }
    else
    {
        $filename .= '.'.$part;
    }
}
```

which checks to see if any of the values in `$parts` (remember, in this case we only have the one item: `39795691`) is in the `allowed_types` or `mime_types` arrays. Since it's a number and isn't in either of those arrays, it concatenates the part into the `$filename` variable and appends the underscore.

Comment: I want to do this BEFORE it is uploaded. If I `echo $config['file_name']` there is no period OR underscore at the end. And with your explanation, you are saying it splits off the last number, do you mean it literally removes the last number and replaces it with a period?

Comment: Well, you set `$config` before you upload. So set $filename before config and set `$config['file_name'] = $filename;`

Comment: No it doesn't remove the last number and replace it with underscore... I updated the answer to hopefully clarify what's going on.

Comment: Wow, great explanation. Thank you. After I read it I was able to just do a much simpler solution. I remove `true` from `uniqid` which disables `more_entropy` and it stopped adding the underscore because of that. Thanks again!