# Codeigniter Rename file on upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm trying to add time as the prefix of the image name along with the original name when uploading, But I couldn't figure it out. Please help me with the following code to add a prefix to my original file name when uploading.

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('upload_form', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function do_upload()
    {


        $config['upload_path'] = 'Public/uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '1024';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';



        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming an uploaded file in CodeIgniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073752/renaming-an-uploaded-file-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65983453/7186739

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You can encrypt file name with use of CI native option:

```
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```

**OR**

You can do it with your own code:

```
$new_name = time().$_FILES["userfiles"]['name'];
$config['file_name'] = $new_name;
```

Answer (score 9):

For some reasons, consecutive calls to the do_upload function doesn't work. It sticks to the first filename set by the first function call

```
$small_photo_url  = $this->upload_photo('picture_small',  $this->next_id.'_small ');
$medium_photo_url = $this->upload_photo('picture_medium', $this->next_id.'_medium');
$large_photo_url  = $this->upload_photo('picture_large',  $this->next_id.'_large ');
```

The filenames will all be "00001_small", "00001_small1", "00001_small2"
given the following configurations

```
function upload_photo($field_name, $filename)
{
    $config['upload_path'] = 'Public/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '1024';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $config['file_name'] = $filename;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())...
```

I think it's because this line doesn't work the second time you call it. It does not set the configurations again

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

==========================================================================
Solution to the problem faced during consecutive do_upload function calls:

```
// re-initialize upload library
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Comment: i'm having the exact same issue... have you came across any solution???

Comment: Found the solution to this problem. I'll put here in case if anyone looking for the solution. Solution is simple...

Load the library in the constructor
`$this->load->library('upload');`

Then initialize the function each time before upload,
`$this->upload->initialize($config);`

it'll work...

Comment: I was facing this issue and resolved with your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
        /* Conf */
        $new_name                   = time().$_FILES["userfiles"]['name'];
        $config['file_name']        = $new_name;
        $config['upload_path']      = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']         = '';
        $config['max_width']        = '';
        $config['max_height']       = '';
        $config['file_ext_tolower'] = TRUE;

      /*  Load the upload library  */   
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Answer (score 2):

For what you are exactly looking for, this worked for me:

```
$path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$newName = "<Whatever name>".".".pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use do_upload() function its rename file name if already exists and upload file

**System->libraries->Upload.php**

default function of do_upload() return true or false
replace

**return $this->upload_path.$this->file_name;**

and in another file

```
 <input type='file' name='userfile'/>


<?php
    $upload_file_name = $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
                $finalname;
                if (!$upload_file_name) {
                    $finalname = 'default.png';
                } else {

                    $split_data_upload_file_name = explode("/", $upload_file_name);
                    foreach ($split_data_upload_file_name as $i => $value) {

                        $finalname = $value;
                    }
                }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['file_name'] = $new_name;
```

Just add it align with the config codes.

Answer (score 0):

This should be after the upload.

Process the filename you want here:

```
$a=$this->upload->data();         
rename($a['full_path'],$a['file_path'].'file_name_you_want');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$config['file_name'] = "yourCustomFileName";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `$config` is with this code: `$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;`
the name of your file will be forced to rename with a encrypt name, just remove the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** Upload file with new customized and specific name (Note: this answer is applicable when you are submitting a unique name of a record, for example student name is a unique value in a record then you will use `$_POST['student_name']`)

```
$config['file_name'] = str_replace(' ', '_', $_POST['anyUniqueValue']);
//any Other unique value that you are using to submit with this file
$config['upload_path'] = './folderName/';
$config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
```

**Solution 2:** Upload file with new unique name

```
$config['file_name'] = time();
$config['upload_path'] = './folderName/';
$config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
```

**Solution 3:** Upload file with new unique name using codeigniter's default option

```
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do multiple file upload, maybe you can try update library Upload.php
on system/libraries/Upload.php. On function do_upload()

```
$this->file_name = $this->_prep_filename($_file['name']);
```

to

```
$this->file_name = time().'_'.$this->_prep_filename($_file['name']);
```