# Rename file upload codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter upload class to upload document files.I need to rename the file.Here is my code,

```
$doc_id = 0;

if(isset($_FILES['doc_file']['name'])) 
{ 
    $config['file_name'] = date('Y/m/d H:i:s')
        . pathinfo($_FILES["doc_file"]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['overwrite'] = 'FALSE';
    $config['max_filename'] = '300';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = 'TRUE';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = 'TRUE';
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
    $config['max_size'] = $this->settings->info->file_size;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (! $this->upload->do_upload('doc_file'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->template->jsonError(lang("error_152") 
            . "<br /><br />"
            . $this->upload->display_errors() 
            . "<br />" 
            . mime_content_type($_FILES['doc_file']['tmp_name'])
        );
    }

    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $doc_id = $this->feed_model->add_doc(array(
        "file_name" => $data['file_name'],
        "file_type" => $data['file_type'],
        "extension" => $data['file_ext'],
        "file_size" => $data['file_size'],
        "userid" => $this->user->info->ID,
        "timestamp" => time()
    ));
}
```

Now I wants the file name as datetime it's uploaded.How can I done this?

Comment: Take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811773/codeigniter-rename-file-on-upload

Comment: `$this->upload->initialize(array(
      "upload_path" => './uploads/',
   "file_name" => 'time().$_FILES['doc_file']['name']',
         "overwrite" => FALSE,
         "max_filename" => 300,
         "encrypt_name" => TRUE,
         "remove_spaces" => TRUE,
         "allowed_types" => "*",
         "max_size" => $this->settings->info->file_size,
    )
   );` Is this one right?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';
$config['max_size'] = 100;
$config['max_width'] = 1024;
$config['max_height'] = 768;
$config['file_name'] = time() . '-' . date("Y-m-d") . '-' . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) 
{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $error);
} 
else 
{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
}
```

Comment: It shows error when move to upload directory like `A problem was encountered while attempting to move the uploaded file to the final destination`

Comment: did you give destination where to upload file like $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

Comment: use the above code it work fine just check where you make mistake

Answer (score 0):

Move all `upload->initialize()` code to **[`$config` array](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#setting-preferences)**  this will give you a better understanding of configurations.

```
$newName = "my-file".date('Y/m/d H:i:s')".".pathinfo($_FILES["fileName"]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['overwrite'] = '';
$config['max_filename'] = '';
$config['encrypt_name'] = '';
$config['remove_spaces'] = '';
$config['allowed_types'] = '';
$config['max_size'] = '';
$config['file_name'] = $newName; # add this

$this->load->library('upload', $config); # or $this->upload->initialize($config)
```

Comment: Gives the error `<br /><br /><p>A problem was encountered while attempting to move the uploaded file to the final destination.</p><br />application/`

Comment: Never before uploaded

Comment: give 777 permission to upload directory then

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['file_name'] = date("Y-m-d_His") . '-' . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
```

or you can use

$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;

in your code. It will rename file to some random string

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: Answer given by @Tassadaq Hussain is also right