# codeigniter: can't upload file, with file name () bracket?

Tags: php, file-upload, codeigniter-3

I am trying to upload files, file name with bracket like sample(1).jpg, sample(2).jpg it's throw the error  as given
`Error: can't upload.The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.`
still,  my configuration as given:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './images/project_docs/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|pptx|docx|xlsx';
$config['max_size'] = '2000000';
$config['remove_spaces'] = true;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
if($this->upload->do_upload('docs')){
    echo  $fileName = $this->upload->data('file_name'); exit();
}else{
    $errors = array('e'=>$this->upload->display_errors("can't upload.")); 
    print_r($errors);exit();
}
```

Comment: may be helpfull : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811773/codeigniter-rename-file-on-upload/37068542

Comment: Have you tried to upload without parenthesis?

Comment: You're uploading a non jpg file that is only jpg in file extension.

Comment: Mr. Gufran Hasan,   sit, i tried, but fail... and Mr. blue sir, no there are many extensions for file as given configuration....   () is issue..

Comment: i tested () name file in another extension, file is uploaded successfully, i don't understand why image file isn't upload.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to `$config['remove_spaces']` because it is true by default which remove spaces, any spaces in the file name will be converted to underscores.
To overcome this problem use `$config['remove_spaces'] = FALSE;`