# Codeigniter renaming image file is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and I'm trying to upload image files.

Everything is working fine, but I am unable to change the uploaded file name to a custom name.

I've tried everything for the past 5 hours, nothing is working.

If anyone can help, it would be great.

I just need to rename the uploaded file to `custom_name.jpg`

#### Controller file

```
 public function uploadimage() {

     $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
     $config['file_name'] = 'custom_name.jpg';
     $config["allowed_types"] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
     $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

     $config["max_size"] = 1024;
     $config["max_width"] = 400;
     $config["max_height"] = 400;
     $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {               
        $this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
    } else {
        echo "success";                                      
    }  

}
```

#### VIEW file

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/uploadimage'); ?>    
<?php echo form_upload('userfile'); ?><br />
<?php echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');?>    
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: From CI page : If set CodeIgniter will rename the uploaded file to this name. The extension provided in the file name must also be an allowed file type. If no extension is provided in the original file_name will be used.  So, maybe try getting uploaded file extension first with PHP and adding that as a variable to the end of the file_name

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21811986

Comment: @WKoppel - can you please elaborate.

Comment: @NageshKatke - that is not what I'm looking for. the link you sent is renaming files based on timestamp. please read my question thanks

Comment: @JackHanson I tried with `$config['file_name'] = 'custom_name.jpg';` at my end it is working fine, uploading file with custom_name. May be the problem is with ordering of config items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove custom extension from file_name and append extension of file uploaded.

```
public function uploadimage() {

 $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
 $config['file_name'] = 'custom_name';
 $config["allowed_types"] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
 $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

 $config["max_size"] = 1024;
 $config["max_width"] = 400;
 $config["max_height"] = 400;
 $this->load->library('upload', $config);

if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) {               
    $this->data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
} else {
    echo "success";                                      
}
```

}

You can also use `rename` function to rename file after successful upload.

Also check these.

Upload directory is writable and the path can be absolute or relative.

Set preferences by calling the `initialize()` method, if you auto-load the class `$this->upload->initialize($config)`

You have some restriction on file size, also check your image size.

Comment: Thanks, Tried it but still not working unfortunately. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: check your autoload file, you loaded upload library there? it shuld be loaded once, either in autoload or here in function.

Comment: // Alternately you can set preferences by calling the ``initialize()`` method. Useful if you auto-load the class ``$this->upload->initialize($config)``

Comment: Thanks, I've checked and removed the duplicate in my function here. But its still not working. Is it possible to force the 'file_name' somehow in CI

Comment: if you removed duplicate from function then add this line ``$this->upload->initialize($config);``

Comment: Hmm, could you please demonstrate? do you mean just replacing `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` with `$this->upload->initialize($config)`

Comment: also make sure upload directory is writable.

Comment: Thanks, but It won't upload at all when I add `$this->upload->initialize($config);` for some reason. Also, the directory is writable, as the files are being uploaded, but just with their default names and not the one I've set `$config['file_name'] = 'custom_name';`

Comment: comment these lines for some time and try again ``$config["max_size"] = 1024;`` ``$config["max_width"] = 400;``  ``$config["max_height"] = 400;``

Comment: Thanks, tried it with extension and `$this->upload->initialize($config);` still not working unfortunately

Comment: if you can show me complete code by some ftp or skype etc, i may help you more,  skype: pakistanimoon786

Comment: OMG Thanks so much! I tried everything and it was driving me crazy. When I removed `$config["max_size"] = 1024; $config["max_width"] = 400; $config["max_height"] = 400;` as you suggested, it worked. But why is this the case haha

Comment: You're a genius my Pakistani friend

Comment: max_size: The maximum size (in kilobytes) that the file can be. Set to zero for no limit. Note: Most PHP installations have their own limit, as specified in the php.ini file. Usually 2 MB (or 2048 KB) by default.

Comment: max_width: The maximum width (in pixels) that the image can be. Set to zero for no limit.

Comment: max_height: The maximum height (in pixels) that the image can be. Set to zero for no limit.

Comment: Now check your image according to these settings.

Comment: Great :) enjoy your day and I wish you the very best and a bright career for your efforts and genius work