# While Uploading Image don't want to save actual image name with space

Tags: codeigniter

In codeigniter while I uploading the image and store image name in database If actual image name is like "abc data.jpg" and I want to store image name like abc_data.jpg and also with this name image should move in uploads folder.

This is my image Upload Code:-

```
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                $config['max_size']             = 5000;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if ($this->upload->do_upload('cover_image')) 
                {
                    $data =$this->upload->data();
                    $data_ary = array(
                                'project_id' => (int)$iProjectId,
                                'image_url' => $data['file_name'],
                                'is_covred_photo' => 'YES'
                        );
                $this->db_project->insert( $this->sTable6 , $data_ary);
                $aResp = array( 'project_images_id' => $this->db->insert_id());
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$config['file_name']`

```
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['max_size']             = 5000;
$config['file_name']            = 'My_new_file_name'; # Add here

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

remove this line as well

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Comment: $config['file_name'] = 'My_new_file_name'; but every time file name is diffrent so how can i make dynamic? I mean If i select any file which name is store with space so how can i store it with underscore?

Comment: before file name use [`str_replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp)

Comment: @KimJones happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$file_name = $_FILES['file_view_name']['name'];
$file_name_pieces = split('_', $file_name);
$new_file_name = '';
$count = 1;

foreach($file_name_pieces as $piece)
{
    if ($count !== 1)
    {
        $piece = ucfirst($piece);
    }

    $new_file_name .= $piece;
    $count++;
}

$config['file_name'] = $new_file_name;
```

[Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073752/renaming-an-uploaded-file-in-codeigniter)